# create thread from other thread throw exception like Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading

hi i am new in android and i need to start 2 webservices on click of button.
first need to call one service and depend on response of that service
need to start second service using thread because i need to call 2nd service periodically.
below is my on click code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class startWork extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MyProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String provider;
    private static ProgressDialog progDailog;
    public static String latitude = "0";
    public static String longitude = "0";
    public static String userid = "";
    public static String password = "";
    public static String activationid = "";
    public static long locationSendingPeriod = 1000;
    public static String role = "Driver";
    public static int j = 0;
    public static int i = 0;
    static final String ACTION = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE";
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            // put your code below to run every second
            try {

                // latitude = "31.794483";
                // longitude = "34.641747";

                String DriverUpdateXml = soapXml.getDriverUpdateLocation(
                        startWork.userid, startWork.password,
                        startWork.activationid, startWork.role, latitude,
                        longitude);

                Soap.getSoapResponse(DriverUpdateXml);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
            // end put your code below to run every second
            mHandler.postAtTime(this, startWork.locationSendingPeriod
                    + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));

        }
    };

**// this is my method which is call onclick of button**

    public void changeWorkStatus(View view) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {
        progressDialog = new MyProgressDialog(this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // progressHandler.postDelayed(progressUpdate, 100);
                    // progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "");

                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(startWork.this);
                    Button btnWork = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartWork);
                    String workText = btnWork.getText().toString();
                    String start_work = getResources().getString(
                            R.string.start_work);
                    String finish_work = getResources().getString(
                            R.string.finish_work);

                    String userid = prefs.getString(CreateDriver.PREFS_UserId,
                            "");
                    String password = prefs.getString(
                            CreateDriver.PREFS_Password, "");
                    String activationid = prefs.getString(
                            CreateDriver.PREFS_ActivationId, "");
                    String role = "Driver";
                    if (workText.equals(start_work)) {
                        // LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)
                        // getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        // LocationListener mlocListener = new
                        // taxiLocationListener();
                        // mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        // LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, (float) 0.01,
                        // mlocListener);

                        // String latitude = "31.794483";
                        // String longitude = "34.641747";

                        String DriverChangeStatus = soapXml.getDriverLogIn(
                                userid, password, activationid, role,
                                latitude.toString(), longitude.toString());

                        String resp = Soap.getSoapResponse(DriverChangeStatus);

                        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = XMLfunctions
                                .XMLfromString(resp);

                        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Status");
                        Element elem = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                        String opt = XMLfunctions.getValue(elem, "Status");

                        nodes = doc
                                .getElementsByTagName("LocationSendingPeriod");
                        elem = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                        locationSendingPeriod = Long.valueOf(XMLfunctions
                                .getValue(elem, "LocationSendingPeriod")) * 1000;

                        if (opt.equals("Success")) {
                            String status = "Available";
                            String DriverAvailable = soapXml
                                    .getDriverChangeStatus(userid, password,
                                            activationid, role, status);
                            Soap.getSoapResponse(DriverAvailable);

                            btnWork.setText(finish_work);
                            btnWork.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_end);

                            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                            mHandler.post(mUpdateTimeTask);

                        }
                    } else {
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

                        String DriverChangeStatus = soapXml.getDriverLogOut(
                                userid, password, activationid, role);

                        String resp = Soap.getSoapResponse(DriverChangeStatus);

                        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = XMLfunctions
                                .XMLfromString(resp);

                        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Status");
                        Element elem = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                        String opt = XMLfunctions.getValue(elem, "Status");

                        if (opt.equals("Success")) {
                            btnWork.setText(start_work);
                            btnWork.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_more_yellow);
                        }
                    }

                    // progressHandler.removeCallbacks(progressUpdate);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(startWork.this)
                            .setMessage(e.toString())
                            .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

i got following run time exception when click on my startwork button (changeworkstatus function called on click of startwork).

**Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**
so my question is how to solve above error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing many things in other thread, then should be event thread, like toast displaying, dismissing dialog, please place your code which need to be in Event thread, in event thread by using either Handler, or Asynctask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
i solve my issue by using async task.